# How to change EJB transaction timeout in Glassfish 4.1.1?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, glassfish-4.1.1

In Glassfish the EJB transaction timeout is set to 120 seconds by default, and I want to change this value.


I know that it can be changed by defining the "cmt-timeout-in-seconds" param in the glassfish-ejb-jar.xml, but I use the Web module with EJB classes in it, and use the glassfish-web.xml respectively.


Is there any way to change the timeout?

**UPD:**


The Transaction Timeout value in the Transaction Service settings has no effect.

```
@Schedule(minute = "*/5", hour = "*", persistent = false)
public void doSomething() {
    log.info("Started");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 119);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        log.info("Interrupted", ex);
    }
    log.info("Finished");
}
```

The code above works fine. But if to change the sleep time to 121 seconds

```
Thread.sleep(1000 * 121);
```

in the GF Server log I see an error:

```
Warning:   EJB5123:Rolling back timed out transaction
```

After this, the service invokes the doSomething() method once more, and in 2 minutes I see errors again:

```
Warning:   EJB5123: Rolling back timed out transaction
Info:   EJB5119:Expunging timer [...] after [2] failed deliveries
```

and the service doesn't invoke the doSomething() method anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if it's a web module, add the sun-ejb-jar.xml (or glassfish-ejb-jar.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 EJB 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-ejb-jar_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
         <ejb>
            <ejb-name>YourEjbName</ejb-name>
            <cmt-timeout-in-seconds>1200</cmt-timeout-in-seconds>
         </ejb>
    </enterprise-beans>
</sun-ejb-jar>
```

Comment: thank you so much, this workaround helped in my case (GF 4.1.1 as well)!

Answer (score 1):

The default value for transaction timeout is **0** (no timeouts), not **120**. There is [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0185/ablsu/index.html) for version 2.1.1 which looks like not outdated.

- Go to [Administrator console](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99ag/index.html) (default port is 4848, http://localhost:4848)
- Left menu: Configurations -> server-config -> Transaction Service
- Field: **Transaction Timeout**
- Server restart

Tested on GlassFish 4.1, shouldn't be much of a difference in 4.1.1.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as the original poster. Used to work fine on Glassfish 4.1 -- only started receiving the error after upgrading to 4.1.1. No timeout value is specified within domain.xml. I'll try adding an explicit timeout of 0, and report back in a few days.

Comment: To confirm, the explicit timeout of 0 has no material effect. My scheduled methods continue to timeout.

Comment: I have experienced the same bug and now there seems to be an issue created for it: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21495

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported bug.

http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21495

With me is when I have a method importing a large amount of data and calling flush.